# Why is the product of these projection matrices a zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

2 vectors are given:
$$
\vec{a_1}=\begin{bmatrix}1 && 2 && -2\end{bmatrix}^T \\
\vec{a_2}=\begin{bmatrix}-2 && 2 && 1\end{bmatrix}^T
$$

To calculate their projection matrices, I used the formula: 
$$ P = \frac{\vec{a}{\vec{a^T}}}{\vec{a^T}{\vec{a}}} $$

and got the following matrices:

$$
\vec{P_1}=\begin{bmatrix}1 && 2 && -2 \\ 2 && 4 && -4 \\ -2 && -4 && 4 \end{bmatrix} \\
\vec{P_2}=\begin{bmatrix}4 && -4 && -2 \\ -4 && 4 && 2 \\ -2 && 2 && 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

And their product is a zero matrix, but I can't explain why.

Is it because the vectors are orthogonal?

Comment: yes. $P_1P_2= a_1a_1^Ta_2a_2^T= a_10a_2^T=0$.Here by $0$ I mean zero matrix of the corresponding dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the two vectors are orthogonal so the kernel of the projection $P_1$ is the image of the projection $P_2$ and then their product is the zero matrix

Comment: I do not undestand how the kernel is an image of the other projection, can you please explain please?

Comment: $P_1$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{span}(a_1)$ so it's the image of $P_1$ and $\operatorname{span}(a_2)$ is the kernel since $a_1\perp a_2$.

Comment: thank you, a lot clearer now

Comment: You're welcome.